# How do I set a model object as its own attribute in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to build a tree using one model/table. I have a model named `Node` and an attribute `root`.  For the root node, I want to set it as the `root`.

I could do this:

```
n = Node.new root:0
# save new query
n.save
n.root = n.id
# save update query
n.save
```

but I want to do this all in one query.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want this gem: https://github.com/rails/acts_as_tree

```
  root      = Category.create("name" => "root")
  child1    = root.children.create("name" => "child1")
  subchild1 = child1.children.create("name" => "subchild1")
```

Basically your Node model will have a parent_id attribute. When it's nil it means that Node is the root.

Comment: thanks, but I just used the tree structure just as an example

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in a single database operation because the id doesn't get assigned until the save occurs and the id isn't available until after that point. You can use a factory (e.g. FactoryGirl) to do it in a single factory operation using the factory mechanism's "after save" hook.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this using `after_commit` callback:

```
after_commit :set_root, :on => :create
def set_root
   self.update_attribute(:root_id, self.id) if root_id == 0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably only by callbacks, since the object have to be saved before fetching it.